# TSQL creating a dynamic report from two tables, one table is holds the headers, other one, data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Imagine a scenario in which I want to get a dynamic report from `[FormValues]` as data, based on `[Title]` column of `[ReportItems]` as header.

I'm really confused how to do it and tried many ways, but none of them work fine.

I should be able to give a procedure a [ReportID] and get the result.

`[FormID]` and `[FieldID]` are relational keys in between two tables.

Any kind help would be highly appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE #ReportItems(
    ReportItemID [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL primary key,
    ReportID [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    FormID [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    FieldID [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    Title nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
) 
GO

insert into #ReportItems
select '5674d274-b146-4251-be0d-a15000e7cefa', '597d37c0-563b-42f0-99be-a15000dc7a65', '01304636-fabe-4a3e-9487-a14b012f9a61', 'ba6b9b1a-92ef-4905-830a-a15000d05f7a', 'First Name'
insert into #ReportItems
select '5674d274-b146-4252-be0d-a15000e7cefa', '597d37c0-563b-42f0-99be-a15000dc7a65', '01304636-fabe-4a3e-9487-a14b012f9a61', 'ba6b9b1a-92ef-4905-830a-a15000d05f7b', 'Last Name'
insert into #ReportItems
select '5674d274-b146-4253-be0d-a15000e7cefa', '597d37c0-563b-42f0-99be-a15000dc7a65', '01304636-fabe-4a3e-9487-a14b012f9a61', 'ba6b9b1a-92ef-4905-830a-a15000d05f7c', 'Age'
GO

CREATE TABLE #FormValues(
    ValueID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL primary key,
    FormID uniqueidentifier NULL,
    FieldID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    UserName nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    Value nvarchar(max) null
)
GO

insert into #FormValues
select 'af6dc400-3972-49ff-9711-a1520002359e', '01304636-fabe-4a3e-9487-a14b012f9a61', 'ba6b9b1a-92ef-4905-830a-a15000d05f7a', 'user 1', 'Mike'
insert into #FormValues
select 'af6dc400-3972-49ff-9721-a1520002359e', '01304636-fabe-4a3e-9487-a14b012f9a61', 'ba6b9b1a-92ef-4905-830a-a15000d05f7b', 'user 1', 'Oscar'
insert into #FormValues
select 'af6dc400-3972-49ff-9731-a1520002359e', '01304636-fabe-4a3e-9487-a14b012f9a61', 'ba6b9b1a-92ef-4905-830a-a15000d05f7c', 'user 1', '20'

insert into #FormValues
select 'af6dc400-3972-49ff-9741-a1520002359e', '01304636-fabe-4a3e-9487-a14b012f9a61', 'ba6b9b1a-92ef-4905-830a-a15000d05f7a', 'user 2', 'Merry'
insert into #FormValues
select 'af6dc400-3972-49ff-9761-a1520002359e', '01304636-fabe-4a3e-9487-a14b012f9a61', 'ba6b9b1a-92ef-4905-830a-a15000d05f7c', 'user 2', '23'

insert into #FormValues
select 'af6dc400-3972-49ff-9771-a1520002359e', '01304636-fabe-4a3e-9487-a14b012f9a61', 'ba6b9b1a-92ef-4905-830a-a15000d05f7a', 'user 3', 'Alen'
insert into #FormValues
select 'af6dc400-3972-49ff-9781-a1520002359e', '01304636-fabe-4a3e-9487-a14b012f9a61', 'ba6b9b1a-92ef-4905-830a-a15000d05f7b', 'user 3', 'Escott'
insert into #FormValues
select 'af6dc400-3972-49ff-9791-a1520002359e', '01304636-fabe-4a3e-9487-a14b012f9a61', 'ba6b9b1a-92ef-4905-830a-a15000d05f7c', 'user 3', '28'
GO

Select * from #ReportItems
Select * from #FormValues
GO
```

And I want such a report as result:

```
User Name   |   First Name  |   Last Name   |   Age
User 1      |   Mike        |   Oscar       |   20
User 2      |   Merry       |               |   23
User 3      |   Alen        |   Escott      |   28
User n      |   ...         |   ...         |   ...



drop table #ReportItems
drop table #FormValues
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the result that you want, you will need to use the [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function.

If all of your values (`title`) are known ahead of time, then you can hard-code a static query:

```
select *
from
(
    select r.Title, f.UserName, f.Value
    from ReportItems r
    left join FormValues f
        on r.FormID = f.FormID
        and r.FieldID = f.FieldID
) src
pivot
(
    max(value)
    for title in ([First Name], [Last Name], Age)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/514f2/4).

But it sounds like you will have an unknown number of `titles` that you want to turn into columns.  If that is the case, then you will want to use dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Title) 
                    from ReportItems
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT UserName,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select r.Title, f.UserName, f.Value
                from ReportItems r
                left join FormValues f
                    on r.FormID = f.FormID
                    and r.FieldID = f.FieldID
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for Title in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/514f2/3)

The result for both would be:

```
| USERNAME | FIRST NAME | LAST NAME | AGE |
-------------------------------------------
|   user 1 |       Mike |     Oscar |  20 |
|   user 2 |      Merry |    (null) |  23 |
|   user 3 |       Alen |    Escott |  28 |
```

If you have a specific `SortOrder` that you need and you have it stored in a table, then when you are getting your list of columns, you will use the following and it will return the columns in the correct order:

```
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Title) 
                    from ReportItems
                    group by Title, sortorder
                    order by sortorder
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b4626/4)

Comment: thanks a lot for you perfect answer. If you dont mind I need to have two more options: 1. how to request the result by [ReportID] 2. how to sort the headers by a column called [SortOrder] in [ReportItems]?

Comment: @Kardo can you edit the sql fiddle with the additional data needed?  When you edit it, post the link here. Or create a new question with the additional details.

Comment: in fact your answer is perfect and works fine. I want to sort the Headers (eg: USERNAME | FIRST NAME | LAST NAME | AGE) to be sorted by a column named [SortOrder] in ReportItems.

Comment: @Kardo see my edit with how you can use the `SortOrder` to keep the columns in the correct order.

Comment: with DISTINCT in select I got this error: select @ cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Title) ------- and by removing DISTINCT it worked fine. Hope removing DISTINCT doesn't cause any problem later.

Comment: @Kardo I updated my answer at the bottom to include the new way to select the columns or you can also see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b4626/4

Comment: Thanks a million. You did a great job! Have a nice time :)

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL='SELECT F.UserName'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL+', MAX(CASE WHEN FieldID='''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), FieldID)+''' THEN F.Value END) AS ['+Title+']
'
FROM #ReportItems
SET @SQL = @SQL+' FROM #FormValues F GROUP BY F.UserName ORDER BY 1'
--select @sql
EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @SQL
```

Later edit: procedure for report based on Report ID an sort columns

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spReport
@ReportID uniqueidentifier,
@SortColumns NVARCHAR(MAX) --shoud be a comma separated list of ReportItems.Title
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @SQL='SELECT F.UserName'
    SELECT @SQL = @SQL+', MAX(CASE WHEN F.FieldID='''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), FieldID)+''' THEN F.Value END) AS ['+Title+']
    '
    FROM ReportItems
    WHERE ReportID=@ReportID --create the dynamic sql only for the items in your report 

    SET @SQL = @SQL+' FROM FormValues F 
    JOIN ReportItems R ON F.FormID=R.FormID
    WHERE R.ReportID = @ReportID
    GROUP BY F.UserName '
    IF @SortColumns<>''
        SET @SQL = @SQL + 'ORDER BY '+@SortColumns -- beware of SQL injection. 
    select @sql
    EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @SQL, N'@ReportID uniqueidentifier', @ReportID=@ReportID
END
```

But, and I can't stress this enough, you have to pay special attention to then @SortColumns parameter, because you're opening yourself to SQL Injection.

Comment: Hi @Daniel, Your answer is correct too. Now I'm confused which one is a better solution to use? Many Thanks again :)

Comment: Well, there was an article by Phil Factor (On http://www.simple-talk.com, I think), that argued that the CASE solutions performed better then the PIVOT one. Anyway, it's your call.

Comment: Actually, the article was written by Jeff Moden on SQLServerCentral http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/63681/

Comment: OK Thanks a lot. One more question: I want to get the result by [ReportID] (in an sp) and also sort the headers by [SortOrder] column in [ReportItems] table. I'd be thankful if you let me know how to figure that?