# How to filter the result of an execute(@query) by where clause?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, filter

I'd like to know how to filter (put where clause) in the result of a dynamic query like this:

```
execute(@query)
```

The problem is the number of columns of @query is dynamic and titles are unknown because the query is the result of a PIVOT:

[TSQL creating a dynamic report from two tables, one table is holds the headers, other one, data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857929/tsql-creating-a-dynamic-report-from-two-tables-one-table-is-holds-the-headers)

The result I want to get is something like this:

```
select * from execute(@query) where column(1) = 'something'
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set @query = N'select * from (' + @query + N') t where [col1] = ''something''';

exec (@query)
```

You could use the unpivoted table to figure out what the name of the column would be, and use this in place of col1.

Comment: Thanks for you solution. It seems it works, but I got another problem:
The col names are in Arabics, so I get this error: Incorrect syntax near '???'. how to avoid this?

Comment: @Hogan, would you reply please?

Comment: Try putting square brackets around the column name, i.e. `where [col1] = ...`

Comment: I tried all these: where [1] (Invalid column name '1'.), where [نام] (Invalid column name '???'.), where N[نام] (Incorrect syntax near '???'.)

Comment: without using and new query set, I get the records correctly.

Comment: OK see updated answer. Notice the N characters. This will ensure the strings are unicode.