# The multi-part identifier "..." could not be bound

Tags: t-sql, subquery, identifier

I get error (The multi-part identifier "f.FormID" could not be bound.) running this query:

```
select f.FormID, f.Title, fv.UserName
    from Forms f join (
        SELECT        FormID
            FROM            Reports
            WHERE        (ReportID = @ReportID)
        UNION 
        SELECT        FormRelations.ForigenFormID
        FROM            FormRelations INNER JOIN
                                    Forms ON FormRelations.ForigenFormID = Forms.FormID
        WHERE        (FormRelations.PrimaryFormID =
                            (SELECT        FormID
                            FROM            Reports
                            WHERE        (ReportID = @ReportID)))
        ) ids
        on f.FormID = ids.FormID

    LEFT OUTER JOIN (select top 1 UserName, FormID from FormValues where FormID = f.FormID and UserName = @UserName) fv
        ON f.FormID = fv.FormID
```

Please someone help me :(

@bluefeet:

I want such a result:

```
01304636-FABE-4A3E-9487-A14B012F9A61    item_1  1234567890
C0455E97-788A-4305-876A-A15000CFE928    item_2  1234567890
7719F37E-7021-4ABD-91ED-A15301830324    item_3  1234567890
```

Comment: You can't use data from one part of join in another part.

Comment: So what should I do? any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use your alias inside of your subquery like that, you might want to look at using the `APPLY` operator:

```
select f.FormID, f.Title, fv.UserName
from Forms f 
join 
(
    SELECT        FormID
    FROM            Reports
    WHERE        (ReportID = @ReportID)
    UNION 
    SELECT        FormRelations.ForigenFormID
    FROM            FormRelations 
    INNER JOIN Forms 
        ON FormRelations.ForigenFormID = Forms.FormID
    WHERE        (FormRelations.PrimaryFormID = (SELECT        FormID
                                                 FROM            Reports
                                                 WHERE        (ReportID = @ReportID)))
) ids
    on f.FormID = ids.FormID
CROSS APPLY
(
    select top 1 UserName, FormID 
    from FormValues 
    where FormID = f.FormID 
        and UserName = @UserName
) fv
```

Or you can use `row_number()`:

```
select f.FormID, f.Title, fv.UserName
from Forms f 
join 
(
    SELECT        FormID
    FROM            Reports
    WHERE        (ReportID = @ReportID)
    UNION 
    SELECT        FormRelations.ForigenFormID
    FROM            FormRelations 
    INNER JOIN Forms 
        ON FormRelations.ForigenFormID = Forms.FormID
    WHERE        (FormRelations.PrimaryFormID = (SELECT        FormID
                                                 FROM            Reports
                                                 WHERE        (ReportID = @ReportID)))
) ids
    on f.FormID = ids.FormID
LEFT JOIN
(
    select UserName, FormID,
        ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by FormID, UserName order by FormID) rn  
    from FormValues 
    where UserName = @UserName
) fv
    on f.FormID = fv.FormID
    and fv.rn = 1
```

Comment: hi :) thanks for your answer. It works but I want to have the null rows for UserNames too.

Comment: @Kardo see my edit, I included a version using `row_number()`

Comment: Thanks a million! That's perfect :) You are so fantastic :)

Comment: would you take a look at this post too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040773/how-to-filter-the-result-of-an-executequery-by-where-clause